# Triangle bisection on non-right angle triangle with known angle and two sides

Tags: geometry

I'm creating 3D road intersections and to create the corner points I detect when the edge vectors of the road intersect. It's extremely accurate.

However, I would like to pre-calculate the corner positions instead. The interior angles of the intersection are all known and are never 90 degrees.

I've boiled it down to this 2D problem where side a and b are always known and the angle specified is random but always known. A and B will always equal each other. Everything else is unknown:

[image]

How do I get the length of line D (bisect)?

Comment: are you bisecting the line C or the angle?

Comment: @stevemarvell: That's the same if the triangle is always isosceles.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I didn't make that assumption

Comment: I would like to bisect the angle (I think), with the bisect line from a point on line C to the lower right point.

Comment: You can't bisect both at the same time unless $A=B$ always

Comment: Ok, in my usage, A will always equal B in length.

Comment: That makes life easier then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the triangle is isosceles, then the intersection of the lines D and the line C forms a right angle and so

$$ D = B \cos\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right) $$